# JQuery Chosen duplicates dropdown

Tags: c#, jquery, jquery-chosen

I'm using jquery chosen library to have research bar on a dropdownlist in a Razor page.
I initialize the dropdownlist on page load and it works.
The problem is it works twice and I have 2 dropdownlist instead of only one (the first is the native razor dropdown and the second is the chosen dropdown).
I don't understand why this behavior occurs. Any help ?

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.BrewerId, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
@(Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.BrewerId, Model.BrewerCollection, "--", new { @class = "form-control chosen-ddl", onchange = "OnBrewerChange(this)" }))
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function InitChosenSearchDrop() {

    if ($(".chosen-ddl").length) {
        $(".chosen-ddl").chosen();
    }
}
</script>
```

Result:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8b0m3.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Finally found out what was the problem.
Just an overriden style made the original dropdown always displayed.